# ajax request issue when sending post request to db mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

i have a problem with an ajax request and a read/write froma  database.

I have this code to submit a form to a database:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myForm').on('submit',function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'save.php',
        type:'POST',

        });
        e.preventDefault(); //=== To Avoid Page Refresh and Fire the Event "Click"===
    });
});
```

and i have the save.php file into the same fold with this code:

```
<?php
include('dbconnection.php');

$Name= $_POST['Name'];
$surname= $_POST['surname'];
$Value= $_POST['Value'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `results`(`Name`, `surname`, `Value`) VALUES('$Name', '$surname','$Value')";

$retval = mysql_query( $sql );

if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}   
?>
```

the only problem is that the values is not saved inside the db..
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: First of all you are not posting the form data in your AJAX call.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: before you do sql insert check if all variables posted to php by adding this `<?php echo "<pre />"; print_r($_POST); ?>` this will print out all posted variables in your ajax script alert .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to serialize your form data and send it to the database -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // var myData = $('#myForm').serialize();
    $('#myForm').on('submit',function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'save.php',
            type:'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize()
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //=== To Avoid Page Refresh and Fire the Event "Click"===
    });
});
```

You should also start using `mysqli_` or PDO to handle your database with as the `mysql_` functions are deprecated. More importantly you should always validate and cleanse your data - you're asking for a SQL Injection attack otherwise.

Comment: You need to open your browser's console and watch the request / response cycle when you perform the action to see if you're getting any errors.

Comment: using the chrome console, after the request, all the var are empty
no error spotted

Comment: I made a change to the code, please try that and let me know what happens in your console.

Comment: same as before, but i don't have any out request seen in the console

Comment: It is working perfectly in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/k9D9G/ Look at the network tab in your console. NOTE: I removed an errant semi-colon after the serialize function.

Comment: ok, but if i use your code the vars are not saved inside the database...
the save.php file seams like it wont do anything

Comment: Is your query running properly? We're transmitting the proper variables now, echo out your SQL statement to make sure it is formed properly. Are you seeing the SQL error returned?

Comment: The save.php file works perfectly, cause i have a working code that refreshes the page. i wanted to run as ajax to prevent the page form reload.
And you can check the code in my first post

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should know that the Mysql php extension is deprecated, you may consider using [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

To solve your problem, you should send the data with your Ajax call. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myForm').on('submit',function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'save.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: {'Name':'John', 'surname': 'Jonny', 'Value':'foo'}
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //=== To Avoid Page Refresh and Fire the Event "Click"===
    });
});
```

To see if it works, you may debug your PHP with this:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```